# How return multiple row while pivoting table in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is my query below in mssql

```
declare @cars as table (
 owners tinyint,
 attribute varchar(20),
 value varchar(20)
)
insert into @cars(owners, attribute, value)
values      (1, 'Make', 'VW'),
            (1, 'Model', 'Rabbit'),
            (1, 'Color', 'Gold'),
            (1, 'Make', 'V'),
            (1, 'Model', 'Rabbi'),
            (1, 'Color', 'Goldddd'),
            (2, 'Make', 'Jeep'),
            (2, 'Model', 'Wrangler'),
            (2, 'Color', 'Gray')


            select * from @cars


  select pvt.owners, pvt.Make, pvt.Model, pvt.Color
from @cars c
pivot (
 min(value)
 for attribute in ([Make],[Model],[Color])
) pvt
```

Above returns

**Owners     make    model   color**

```
  1     v    rabbi gold

  2     jeep wrangler gray
```

but i need to return like

**Owners     make    model   color**

```
  1     v    rabbi gold
  1     vw   rabbit golddd
  2     jeep wrangler gray

 how is possible?
```

Comment: why min(value) ? if you want all, use max(value)

Comment: why have you joined VW with Goldddd instead of Gold?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an additional field to your data that gives each owners/attribute combination a unique value:

```
SELECT  pvt.owners, pvt.Make, pvt.Model, pvt.Color
FROM    (   SELECT  Owners, 
                    Attribute, 
                    Value, 
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Owners, Attribute ORDER BY Value)
            FROM    @Cars
        ) c
        PIVOT
        (   MIN(Value)
            FOR Attribute IN ([Make], [Model], [Color])
        ) pvt
ORDER BY Owners, Make, Model, Color;
```

The key here is rather than just passing `@cars` to the pivot, the subquery adds an additional column to make the table being pivoted this:

```
Owners  Attribute   Value   RowNum
1       Color       Gold        1
1       Color       Goldddd     2
1       Make        V           1
1       Make        VW          2
1       Model       Rabbi       1
1       Model       Rabbit      2
2       Color       Gray        1
2       Make        Jeep        1
2       Model       Wrangler    1
```

So, that now there is an additional column to differentiate `Gold` from `Goldddd` for example, forcing them onto different rows in the pivot output.

You will run into problems though if there isn't a duplicate for all attributes, where there is missing data you will end up with NULL, e.g if you were to remove the values `(1, 'Color', 'Goldddd')` from your data, then the output would be:

```
owners  Make    Model       Color
1       V       Rabbi       Gold
1       VW      Rabbit      NULL
2       Jeep    Wrangler    Gray
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b56f/1)**